# Android - Pass extra parameter to AsyncTask

Tags: android, parameters, android-asynctask

I have a quastion about an AsyncTask, I hope somone could give me some advice. I am performing AsyncTasks to get data from internet. The task is in a separate class. I have multiple AsyncTasks that do exactly the same action, but they get called at different moments and pass data back to different methods. In the current AsyncTask i can exucute it and give one or more url's as parameter.

My question is: is there a way to send an extra parameter to the AsyncTask so that I can use a switch case in the onPostExecute to decide where the webdata should go?

This is one of the AsyncTask classes:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetContactpersoonFromWeb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
String result = "";
String webData;
FirstScreen activity;

public GetContactpersoonFromWeb(FirstScreen activity)
{
    this.activity = activity;
}


protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext); 

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = null; //vanaf niks beginnen
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line + "\n"; 
        }   
        this.webData = result;        
    }
    catch (Exception e) {           
        Log.d("info","error bij het ophalen van de data", e);
    }
    return this.webData;            
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.webData = result;
    activity.getContactpersoonData(webData); 
 }
```

}

The difference with the other AsyncTasks is the last rule: `activity.getFabricData(webData);`
In an other class it is: `activity.getMachineData(webData);` etc..

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this by using only 1 class? I think using 7 classes with only 1 rule of diffrence is not the best way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pass the value to the constructor of asynctask and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the date based on which you will perform your `switch` in your constructor

```
public GetContactpersoonFromWeb(FirstScreen activity,int yourExtraData)
{
   this.activity = activity;
   mExtraData = extraData;
}
```

and then use `mExtraData` in your `onPostExecute`

Comment: Well, that was way more simple than i tought.. It works, thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an extra variable in the `AsyncTask` and add the extra parameter in the constructor like

```
public GetContactpersoonFromWeb(FirstScreen activity,int extra)
```

{

```
this.activity = activity;
    this.extra=extra;
```

}

Then you can use this value in a switch case like

```
switch(extra){`
................
.................
```

Answer (score 0):

@insomniac's answer will work fine, but there's another option to consider.  Provided you know where the data needs to go before creating the `AsyncTask`, another option for different `onPostExecute()` behavior is to use polymorphism rather than a `switch`.  This allows you to add another type of behavior in the future without the risk of breaking existing code.  The technique is explained here:  http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

In your case you'd move the code from `GetContactpersoonFromWeb` to an abstract base class, say, `GetFromWeb`, then have `GetContactpersoonFromWeb` inherit from `GetFromWeb` and override `onPostExecute()`.  Repeat for `FabricData` and `MachineData`.